# How to select a varying length substring in XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have these nodes:

```
  <JConfig diffgr:id="JobSubmissionConfig1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
    <JConfigID>12314</JConfigID>
    <JConfigName>Custom_Assets15</JConfigName>
    <DataOwnerID>21873497</DataOwnerID>
    <RunAsUserID>21873497</RunAsUserID>
    <StatusChgEmailAddresses>admin@someemail.com</StatusChgEmailAddresses>
    <InputFolder>Input\JVEND_DATA_ADMIN_12314</InputFolder>
    <HistoryFolder>Processed\JVEND_DATA_ADMIN_12314</HistoryFolder>
 </JConfig>
```

I am interested in only in the `InputFolder` node value starting after `"Input\"`, i.e `"JVEND_DATA_ADMIN_12314"`, but the problem is this value will keep on changing (in number of characters) depending on the user id I use.

I tried

```
   substring(//*[local-name()='InputFolder']/text(), 7, 20)
```

This did work with some of the user ids which matched the number of characters, since folder name will be dependent on the User id I use, it could be for some other user id come as `"ABVEND_DATA_ADMIN_124587"`.

Give me some solution which can let me capture the value after `"Input\"` and then use it in my next request.

Comment: @kjhughes this is what I was thinking,,, and you answered before I could think more ,,, great and many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [substring-after()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring-after):

```
substring-after(//*[local-name()='InputFolder']/text(), 'Input\')
```

Or, you can drop the third argument to [substring()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring),

```
substring(//*[local-name()='InputFolder']/text(), 7)
```

and it'll default to the end of the string.

Note that you can probably simplify your XPath to just `//InputFolder` since

1. there do not appear to be any namespaces in play, and
2. the string value of `InputFolder` will yield the value you want.